# Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() on Gentoo

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, gentoo

I set up Apache2 and PHP using these two manuals

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/PHP
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Apache/it

on a x86_64 machine

Now the problem is that PHP seems to have no extensions (mysql, mysqli,...) and now of course I cannot use functions defined in those extensions for example mysql_connect().

How can I cope with this problem?

I've already checked the output of phpinfo() and I noticed that the set extension_dir (/usr/lib64/php5.6/lib/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226) is empty, it doesn't exist.

I've also tried a brutal way, since I can't find extensions installed on my system I downloaded the rpm php-mysql and extracted (it contains the folder extension with mysql.so, mysqli.so etc...) and set the php.ini properly. Same result.

Comment: download xampp and get rid of all of this

Comment: thx man, xampp is heaven!